# Should we pursue knowledge for the sake of knowledge without considering the possible consequences?

Tags: ethics, epistemology, knowledge, utilitarianism, consequentialism

For example, should Alfred Noble be blamed for suicide bombers as he created dynamite?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. You question is too broad and open-ended to be a good fit for our site, they can be addressed by reading encyclopedias, like [Wikipedia, Ethics of Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethics_of_technology) or [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/technology/#EthiSociAspeTech). We take more pointed and specific questions that come up after general reading.

Comment: You can also see Heidegger’s later work, and Adorno and the books of Nicolas Maxwell. Some of Maxwell’s publications are listed here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Maxwell

Comment: Knowledge is vital to Humanity. Otherwise, we wouldn't have the vast number of creations and inventions in this world and outside our world by humans. So it is good mostly at first. The implementation of that knowledge is notable here. Sometimes before and after acquiring the knowledge we need to ask critical questions. Who, What, How, Why. “Time, as it grows old, teaches all things.” -- Aeschylus, Prometheus Bound. So if an innocent person discovered knowledge for good purpose first and later it was used against humanity that's where the red flag stands out.

Answer (score 1):

You may find useful verses 9-11 of the [Isa](https://www.sriaurobindoashram.org/sriaurobindo/downloadpdf.php?id=32)
(Isavasya) upanishad :

> Into blind darkness enter those who follow the way of ignorance. Into ever greater darkness those who devote themselves to knowledge alone
>
> He who knows That as both in one, the Knowledge and the Ignorance, by the Ignorance crosses beyond death and by
> the Knowledge enjoys Immortality.